# Problemas de compatibilidad de Bootstrap en Nokia

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo un sistema desarrollado en Bootstrap y jQuery, al hacer pruebas en distintos dispositivos encontré un problema en un Nokia 2.4, en lugar de traer los datos con jQuery desde la base de datos solo muestra esto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
 $(document).on("click",".editar",function(){
     var pos = $(".editar").index(this);
     var cod, desc, ord, mesa;
     $("#mydatatable tbody tr:eq("+pos+")").find("td:eq(2)").each(function(){
        cod = $(this).html(); 
     });
     $("#mydatatable tbody tr:eq("+pos+")").find("td:eq(0)").each(function(){
        desc = $(this).html(); 
     });
     $("#mydatatable tbody tr:eq("+pos+")").find("td:eq(1)").each(function(){
        ord = $(this).html(); 
     });
     $("#mydatatable tbody tr:eq("+pos+")").find("td:eq(3)").each(function(){
        mesa = $(this).html(); 
     });
     $("#cod_edit").val(cod);
     $("#desc_edit").val(desc);
     $("#ord_edit").val(ord);
     $("#mesa_edit").val(mesa);
     $("#desc_edit").focus();
  });
  //Guardar editar
  $(document).on("click","#guardar_edit",function(){ 
    var cod= $("#cod_edit").val();
    var desc= $("#desc_edit").val();
    var ord= $("#ord_edit").val();
    var mesa= $("#mesa_edit").val();
     if(desc!==""){
         $.ajax({
             url: "grabar.php",
             type: "POST",
             data: {ord:ord,desc:desc, cod: cod, mesa: mesa}
         }).done(function(msg){
                $("#cerrar").click();
                humane.log("<span class='fa fa-check'></span> "+msg,
                { timeout: 4000, clickToClose: true, addnCls: 'humane-flatty-success' });
                refrescarDatos();
         });
     }else{
         humane.log("<span class='fa fa-info'></span> Campos Vacio", 
         { timeout: 4000, clickToClose: true, addnCls: 'humane-flatty-warning' });
     }
     
  });
```

Este es el código en jQuery que debería ser mostrado así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene alguna idea de por que ocurre esto o como solucionarlo?

Comment: Nokia es solo el dispositivo físico. Lo que tienes que averiguar es el sistema operativo que tiene para verificar si ocurre en todos o solo en nokia.

Comment: El Nokia 2.4 tiene Android 10, pero en ningún otro dispositivo Android he tenido problemas, la segunda captura de pantalla es de un Xiaomi Redmi 10c

Comment: Segun veo el Xiami Redmi 10c usa "MIUI 13 basado en Android 11"... debes buscar otro android 10, y si puede ser en el mismo modelo de nokia mejor que mejor, para ir delimitando mejor el problema

Comment: Es que eso que te aparece dentro de los campos tampoco tiene demasiado sentido... porque en tu código tu ves donde pone eso de `<font style`?

Comment: Esa es la cuestión, en ninguna parte de mi código figura esa linea de código, además en el label donde debería decir Mesa figura como "colina baja" así que tampoco entiendo por que sale así

Comment: Tendrá un pegasus metido o algun spyware, jeje... por eso te decia que lo probaras, si puedes, en otro nokia igual en versión y modelo

Comment: Que navegador estás usando en ese móvil? Probaste con diferentes navegadores? Igual puedes ingresar al código fuente del lado front si escribes `view-source:` al inicio de tu URL, a lo mejor te da pistas de lo que sucede.